# How do i update content of a particular tag in local html page using bs4 python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to change content of a `<p>`  tag in a HTML DOM using. I have used `bs4` to successfully select the particular tag and update it but how do i save it back to HTML file?.

**Python code**

```
import bs4
exampleFile = open('stefan/index.html')
exampleSoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(exampleFile.read())
test="testing testing"
elems = exampleSoup.select('#page_main_text')
print(elems[0].getText())

tag=exampleSoup.p
tag.string=test
print(tag)
```

**HTML**

```
<p class="grey" id="page_main_text">It was an awesome experience to grow up with you. I can recall all the memories that we shared together. We laughed together and cried together. All these things are to remind you – happy birthday.</p>
```

Comment: Just open a file and write to it instead of calling `print`. See https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#output

Comment: @FullName I need to update that same html file. How will i select that particular tag?

Comment: Just `open('stefan/index.html', "w")` and write `exampleSoup` to it.

Comment: @FullName nI am getting error. TypeError: must be str, not BeautifulSoup

Comment: @FullName thanks its working now. Used prettify before writing